# Android: Limit drag & drop of object

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, motionevent

I have a Activity. On this Activity I have a Relative Layout. On this layout I have placed several custom objects from a class that extends RelativeLayout.
It kind of looks like a chessboard (it isn't, but so you know what I'm talking about).
I now want to be able to touch one of this objects and drag it to one of the 4 adjacent fields, swapping it against the one there.
I thought the most simple way would be to use androids drag & drop.

I used setOnTouchListener and setOnDragListener for every object, so every object can be touched and dragged onto another object.
I used [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/try-androids-useful-drag-and-drop-api/) tutorial, should be easier for you to read than just the code, but here it is:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
            v.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent e) {
    if (e.getAction()==DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
        View view = (View) e.getLocalState();
        ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        from.removeView(view);
        MyCustomViewClass to = (MyCustomViewClass) v;
        to.addView(view);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now I am wondering how I could limit where a object could be dropped. I want it to be able to be moved just to the 4 adjacent fields (not only by limiting the draglistener, I also don't want the object to be moved beyond this objects, no matter how far the finger tries to drag it).
I hope you get what I mean, if not please ask.
So this question is all about what I can do with this drag & drop I guess. Is it possible to somehow detect where the finger is before dropping? Is it possible to limit the dragging to the straight x and y axis? Or is there a way to know the direction of that dragging movement, allowing me to 1) know the object I would swap with and 2) moving the other object before the drop, making it look like the objects are just swapping?

**Edit:**
I got the direction, since I can calculate it from `view.getX`, `view.getY` (coords are inside my startobject) and `v.getX` and `v.getY` (coords from the object I'm over) in onDrag when the dragEvent is ACTION_ENTERED.
Now I try to figure out either how to set the dragshadows position to the object I want it to be over, or to only allow dragging in my direction and ending the drag over the next object.
Further help or ideas still appreciated.

Comment: You could specialize `DragShadowBuilder` and override the onDraw method. I assume that the `Canvas` argument is pre-configured with a transformation `Matrix` that will translate the view to the touch point location. You could read that translation by applying the matrix on a `PointF`. If the translation is out of bounds you can concatenate another translation to the Canvas that keeps the shadow view within the boundaries.

Comment: ...I think it would be less of a hassle if you would allow dragging the object all over the game board. If it is an invalid field, you could just highlight it with red color for example, or change the shadow view graphic with something like big red X or so.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Thanks for your input, I will think about how it could fit and play a bit with the shadow. Right now I am about to figure what direction the drag is, I guess it should be somehow possible to just set the shadow to the next objects position instead of limiting the dragging.